# Why do I receive foreign key conflict error when inserting value into foreign key field. Value being inserted matches primary key in reference table

Tags: php, sql-server, foreign-keys, key

I insert a record into a table using autoincrement primary key.  Then I access the new primary key and try to insert it into a field that is foreign key to the new primary record.  Then receive foreign key error.  Code is:

```
/******************  Insert new record in session table ************************/
$insBC2020sql = "insert into session (auctionid,auctiondate,created,lastupdated,sessiondate) output inserted.*
    values ('$auctionid','$saledt','$today','$today','$today')";

$insBC2020res = odbc_exec($conn_1,$insBC2020sql);

if (!$insBC2020res) {
    exit("Request Error --" . odbc_errormsg($conn_1));
}
/*********************  Retrieve primary key from last insert **************************/
while (odbc_fetch_row($insBC2020res)) {
        $sessionid    = odbc_result($insBC2020res, 1);

    echo "\r\n".$sessionid. "  ".$customerid;
}
}
/*************************  Insert retrived value into reference table ********************/
$inssql = "insert into bidcall2020.dbo.customersession (customerid,sessionid)
       values ('$customerid','$sessionid')";
echo $inssql."\r\n";

$insres = odbc_exec($conn_1, $inssql);
if (!$insres) {
    exit("Request Error --" . odbc_errormsg($conn_1));
}
```

Get foreign key conflict error.  Sessionid is a foreign key.  Value retrieved does match value in primary table.

Comment: What is the exact foreign key error? I disagree with the answer below. You are returning the last inserted value via your OUTPUT clause on the INSERT statement. So that part should be OK. Can't say I like retrieving the column by position though (i.e. column 1 instead of the column name). Any chance you can just change the output clause to say "inserted.sessionid" instead of "inserted.*", just in case its the wrong column?

Otherwise, it looks OK. Do the right values get echoed back in your echo statement?

Where does the $customerid value come from? Is it already known at that point?

Comment: Thanks - I got it to work - will change to 'inserted.sessionid'.

Comment: Yep, I really don't like using ordinal values to retrieve columns. I don't use that library but I'll bet there's a way to map a column name to an ordinal.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$sessionid    = odbc_result($insBC2020res, 0);
```

instead of

```
$sessionid    = odbc_result($insBC2020res, 1);
```